# UISearchController inside UIViewController with view before it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

My task is to implement inside `UIViewController` (Not `TableVC`) search bar with UISegmentedControl. I want to make something like

[image]

But my result is

[image]

How to prevent UINavigationBar from hiding (iOS 8)? And how to place UISearchBar below segmentedControl?

Inside `viewDidLoad`

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

#pragma mark - UISearchControllerDelegate & UISearchResultsDelegate

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
    [self updateFilteredContentForAirlineName:searchString];
    if (self.searchController.searchResultsController) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;
        MBQuestionsSearchResultVC *vc = (MBQuestionsSearchResultVC *)navController.topViewController;
        vc.searchResults = self.searchResults;
        [vc.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I also try to make constraints programmatically

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    [self.searchController.searchBar mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.mas_equalTo(self.segmentedControl.mas_bottom).with.offset(10.f);
        make.leading.mas_equalTo(self.view);
        make.trailing.mas_equalTo(self.view);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(44.f);
    }];
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

But the result is not good

[image]

Thanks in advance :(